# Pivot for the same gender

Tags: sql

How do i have multiple pivot. I would like to achieve the result as highlighted below.[image]
For each Grade and each Gender, i would like to have the TotalA and Total B values aligned in 4 columns in a single row. My final result need to contain all 10 columns shown below.

My desired output [Need to contain 2 rows with GENDER column remained]:
[image]
I tried with below: But the script removed my Gender column and unable to pivot 2 columns (TotalA, TotalB) into 4 additional columns at the same time.

```
   SELECT *,
  [TotalA_Male] = [M],
  [TotalB_Female] = [F]
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM table) AS s
  PIVOT 
  (
    MAX(TotalA) FOR [Gender] IN ([M],[F])
  ) AS p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want a pivot at all. You are looking to find the partial sum of your total column, grouped by some key columns (it looks like `Country` and `Grade` in this case) . Window functions let you perform this partial sum. However, they won't filter by gender. You'll need to use a `CASE` expression inside the `SUM()` to only include male or female in your partial sums:

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN TotalA ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, Grade) AS TotalA_Male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN TotalA ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, Grade) AS TotalA_Female,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN TotalB ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, Grade) AS TotalB_Male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN TotalB ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, Grade) AS TotalB_Female
  FROM totals
```

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Basically, the window functions let you do a `GROUP BY` as part of a single column expression in the `SELECT` list. The result of the aggregate and group by is included in every row, just as if it were any other expression. Note how there is no `GROUP BY` or `PIVOT` in the rest of the query. The `PARTITION BY` in the `OVER()` clause works like a `GROUP BY`, specifying how to group the rows in the resultset for the purposes of performing the specified aggregation (in this case, `SUM()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can only pivot on a single column so what you need to to is unpivot those TotalA and TotalB columns into rows and then generate a single column based on gender and the total and use that in a pivot...

```
select * from (
    select 
        grade,
        /* combine the columns for a pivot */
        total_gender_details = details + '_' + gender,
        totals
     from

        (values
        (1, 'F', cast(7.11321 as float), cast(15.55607 as float)), 
        (1, 'M', 6.31913, 15.50801),
        (2, 'F', 5.26457, 6.94687), 
        (2, 'M', 6.34666, 9.29783) 
        ) t(grade,gender,totalA,totalB)

        /* unpivot the totals into rows */
        unpivot (
            totals
            for details in ([totalA], [totalB])
        ) up
) t
pivot (
    sum(totals)
    for total_gender_details in ([totalA_M],[totalA_F],[totalB_M],[totalB_F])
) p
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i need the Gender column to be appeared in the end result too. I tried to add the Gender in the SELECT, but that breaks the PIVOT..

Comment: oh, that's kind of weird